# Get total value of a related list

Tags: apex, related-list, flow, process-builder

Suppose I have "**SUB_ACCOUNT__c**" object and I've created it as a child object of "**Account**". Now "**SUB_ACCOUNT__c**" has a field "**value__c**" which is number in type. I also created a custom field for "**Account**" which is "**totalSubAccountValue__c**". Now what I need is, to get the data from "**SUB_ACCOUNT__c.value__c**" that belongs to a certain Account and add all its data and put the total to the custom field "**Account.totalSubAccountValue__c**". The same concept applied when I will create or update "**SUB_ACCOUNT__c**". My question is, What is the best thing to do this? Apex? Can I do it using the process builder or Flow? Are there any other methods?

Answer (score 1):

If you've created a master-detail relationship from the child object to the account (if not, change the lookup to master-detail), then you could use **Roll Up Summary Fields** to automatically calculate the value.

[Read this part of the documentation for more info.](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm)

You could certainly use an Apex Trigger too or other methods, though this will be your quickest, cleanest and best practice method.

Comment: The problem is that I can't change my lookup to master-detail because the related field is not required. There are "SUB_ACCOUNT__c" data that is not related to account.

Comment: Would've been good to state that in the original question :). In that case I suggest you to use a trigger. Have a look at this - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33650/how-to-write-a-rollup-summary-trigger-for-a-lookup-relationship and http://www.bachovski.com/2015/03/roll-up-summary-trigger-for-lookup.html

Comment: Personally I haven't done it by it looks like you can also use a flow: http://www.salesforceweek.ly/2015/02/how-to-create-roll-up-summaries-using-flow.html

Comment: Does not seem to make sense why you would have a "Sub Account" without a main account.....May just be a terminology thing...but SUB generally leads one to believe that there should be a main or parent account

Comment: @Eric actually its not a real name. I just use it as an example.