# How to get detail (Opportunity) records via master (Account) ID (preferrably without DML)

Tags: apex, trigger, dml

I've got to update a custom field on Account.

This field is the number of Opportunities of that Account that are "Prospecting".

I've written a trigger for this.

The problem is, I've solved it using a DML statement inside a loop (yes, i know, this is very bad).

I donot know any other way to do this, without using DML in loops.

```
for(account acc_in_loop = trigger.new)
{
    list<opportunity> opp_list = [Select Id, Stagename from Opportunity where AccountID =: acc_in_loop.id];

    for(opportunity opp_in_loop : opp_list)
    {
        if condition etc....
    } 

    acc_updt_list.add(acc_in_loop);
}
insert acc_updt_list;
```

Any tips/help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at using a roll up summary field? Also may help: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33650/how-to-write-a-rollup-summary-trigger-for-a-lookup-relationship

Comment: Hello Girbot, thats an option, but I wish to try with triggers. The above question is to help me understand relationships better, and how to get child records from parent ID.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to do a simple count, you should use a [Roll-Up Summary Field](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm)

If that doesn't work for you and you need more complex logic, you can reduce the number of queries with a [subquery](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using.htm#sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using)

```java
for(Account a : [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, StageName from Opportunities) FROM Account WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new]){
    Integer count = 0;
    for(Opportunity opp : a.Opportunities){
        if(opp.StageName = 'Prospecting') count = count+1;
    }
    a.MyCountField__c = count;
}
```

This way you only query once.

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure whats going on in the first line, will it not call DML every time in the loop?

Comment: No. It'll only query once and then loop through the results. 

P.s.: DML are changes to the database (update, insert, delete, etc...). The 'selects' are called _queries_

Comment: Oh, didnt know THAT! I just lump query + changes as DML. Well ty for showing me the way!

Comment: perfect, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

There are many errors in your code ou can do something like this

```
for(account acc_in_loop : [Select id ,no_Of_opp__c, ( select Id from Opportunities where stagename ='Prospecting') from account where ID IN: trigger.new)
{
    acc_in_loop.no_Of_opp__c = acc_in_loop.Opportunities.size();
}
```

And put this code in before update of account and you don't need any DML.

Comment: but will it not call the DML every single time in the loop? for eg, I have updated 200 accounts via Data Loader, will it not exceed the DML limit?

Comment: @fraglord did you see any dml in my code. No it will not call the DML. Use this in before update

Comment: are you **SURE** that `[Select id ,no_Of_opp__c, ( select Id from Opportunities where stagename ='Prospecting') from account where ID IN: trigger.new]` will not count for governor limit?

Comment: This is a SOQL and will count in governor limit. You are asking about DML.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [roll up summary](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&language=en) field on Account object which will calculate the  opportunities with Prospecting status for Account.

> A roll-up summary field calculates values from related records, such
>   as those in a related list. You can create a roll-up summary field to
>   display a value in a master record based on the values of fields in a
>   detail record. The detail record must be related to the master through
>   a master-detail relationship.

By using this way, you don't requied to write a code.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I know this method, but I'm trying to do this with code.