# Sum up all the Unit cost from Asset to Account

Tags: salesforce1-app, salesforce-id, sales

I am having a Unit Cost field in my Asset. There can be multiple asset for single account.

So, Now i need to add all the Unit Cost associated in Asset to Annual Revenue in Account.

No 'Roll up Summary' field is not working from Account because of relationship.
Is there any way i can achieve this by configuration rather than by trigger?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1. Build your own trigger to do a rollup.
2. Better and configurable way is to use this great tool developed by Andrew Fawcett : [`Declarative Rollup Summary`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Declarative_Rollup_Summary_Tool_for_Force.com_Lookup_Relationships)

   - Package URL can be found in `Packaged Release History` section of the [`github repo`](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries).

Comment: Thanks Rahul. Do you have some sample Trigger in place?

Comment: Here is a great answer by Mohit - [How to write a rollup summary trigger for a lookup relationship
](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/33654/4726)