# I am trying To write a trigger in which i have below requirement .i Copied this code and trying to apply on Account And Contact

Tags: trigger

Trigger to Sum values (like Lookup relationship)

```
trigger NewLucy on Contact (after insert, after delete, after update) {
   if(Trigger.isInsert){
      try {
         for (Contact co : Trigger.new) {
            Account po = [SELECT Id,SumAllContactCurrency__c  FROM Account WHERE Id = :co.AccountId];
            List<Contact> l_co = [SELECT Id,amount__c FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :po.Id];
            for(Contact am_co : l_co) {
               amount += am_co.Amount__c;  
            }
            po.SumAllContactCurrency__c = amount;
            update po;
         }
      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.debug(e);
      }
   }

   if(Trigger.isAfter) {
      if(Trigger.isUpdate) {
         try {
            for (Contact co : Trigger.old) {
               Account po = [SELECT Id,SumAllContactCurrency__c  FROM Account WHERE Id = :co.AccountId];
               List<Contact> l_co = [SELECT Id,amount__c FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :po.Id];
               for(Contact am_co : l_co) {
                  amount += am_co.Amount__c;  
               }
               po.SumAllContactCurrency__c = amount;
               update po;
            }
         } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug(e);
         }
      }
      
      if(Trigger.isDelete){
         try {
            for (Contact co : Trigger.old){
               Account po = [SELECT Id,SumAllContactCurrency__c  FROM Account WHERE Id = :co.AccountId];
               List<Contact> l_co = [SELECT Id,amount__c FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :po.Id];
               for(Contact am_co : l_co) {
                  amount += am_co.Amount__c;  
               }
               po.SumAllContactCurrency__c = amount;
               update po;
            }
         } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug(e);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You may want to bulkify this trigger by moving the queries and DML's out of for loop. [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/success-cloud-coding-conventions/improve-your-apex-code-sc) is a good place to start. In terms of your trigger, once bulkified, it should work fine. Here is a similar question which lists several ways to achieve what you are trying to do. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33650/how-to-write-a-rollup-summary-trigger-for-a-lookup-relationship

Comment: What manjit said ^^^, plus: If this trigger is firing and you are getting errors, or unexpected results, or unexpected debug messages, please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/346721/edit) your post and add that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SOQL and DML inside loop can be taken out and by using maps, it can be handled in a better manner. Check below code for insert scenario, it will help you understand the use of maps and you can modify the update and delete scenarios accordingly

```
 trigger ContactTrigger on  Contact (after insert, after delete, after update) {
   if(Trigger.isInsert){
      try {
          Set<Id> relatedAccIds = new Set<id>();
          for(Contact co : trigger.new){
              if(co.accountid <> null){
                  relatedAccIds.add(co.accountId);
              }
          }
          List<Account> relatedAccountList = [SELECT Id, SumAllContactCurrency__c  FROM Account WHERE Id in :relatedAccIds];
          List<Contact> l_co = [SELECT Id, amount__c FROM Contact WHERE AccountId in :relatedAccIds];
          Map<Id, Account> accountToAmountMap = new map<Id, Account>();
          for(Contact conObj : l_co) {
              if(accountToAmountMap.containsKey(conObj.accountId)){
                  accountToAmountMap.get(conObj.accountid).SumAllContactCurrency__c += am_co.Amount__c;
              }
              else{
                  accountToAmountMap.put(conObj.accountid, new Account(id = conObj.accountid, SumAllContactCurrency__c = conObj.Amount__c));
              }
              //amount += am_co.Amount__c;  
          }
         if(accountToAmountMap <> null)
            update accountToAmountMap.value();
         }
      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.debug(e);
      }
   }
```